# how to get an ID from a button calling with for loop

Tags: android, button

I want to get the id from buttons calling with for loop from the XML​

```
 favTNitem[i].setOnClickListener (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

//log my id number
                                Log.d("miButton",""+id);
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning an AdapterView.OnItemClickListener where tou should assign a View.OnClickListener. The OnClick method of the OnItemClickListener receives a View as parameter and the id of the clicked View can be accessed by the getId() method of it

```
public void onClick(View v) {
     //this is the clicked Button id
     int id = v.getId();
}
```

Comment: thank you, I found another way, is working but I i will test with your code too

Answer (score 0):

I fix as this way

```
    favTNitem[i].setId(identification);
                    favTNitem[i].setClickable(true);
final int finalI = i;
                    favTNitem[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            Log.d("myTag", "click"+finalI);
                        }
                    });
```